# Backbone.Model.extend does not create instance properties

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and JS, so correct me if I am wrong...

Using the example from backbone.js site,

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() { ... },
    author: function() { ... },
    coordinates: function() { ... },
    allowedToEdit: function(account) {
        return true;
    } 
});
```

Backbone.js says,

> "To create a Model class of your own, you extend Backbone.Model and provide instance properties, as >well as optional classProperties to be attached directly to the constructor function."

So i create two objects,

```
var n1 = new Note;
var n2 = new Note;
```

Now the properties autor, allowedToEdit coordinates etc., are not instance properties of n1 and n2. They are created under the **proto** link. How do I create instance properties in backbone.js

Also, if I try to modify a inherited property in javascript in an object, the inherited property is not changed. Instead, a new property with the same name is created in the objects instance properties. How do I achive this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: you should do `n1.get("author")` rather than `n1.author` because that will allow a trigger of `change` event. If you are looking for something else then this is possible `var note = Backbone.Model.extend({},{hello:function(){alert('Hi Dude');}});` and then you can use it like `note.hello();` but every instance does not have them just the class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are a bit confused about what extend does.  Extend is analogous to inheritance.  If you extend the `Model` in this way, you create a derived "class" called `Note` which now has these member functions.

But that is not what you want, I don't think.  You want a model with these DATA properties.  Adding data to an instance is simple:

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var n1 = new Note({
    author: "Gautham",
    coordinates: {x: 200, y: 100},
    allowedToEdit: true
});

var author = n1.get("author");
```

In other words, data properties on Backbone models are dynamic.  You don't need to declare them in your `Note` derivation.

If, however, you would like the `Note` derivation to have properties that look this way, you can always define them to proxy through to the `get` function:

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    author: function() { return this.get('author'); },
    coordinates: function() { return this.get('coordinates'); }
    allowedToEdit: function() { return this.get('allowedToEdit'); }
});
var n1 = new Note({...});
var author = n1.author();
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to use defaults attribute, that are the behavior that you are expecting:

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:function(){
    return {
      author : 'Default author',
      coordinates : [0,0],
    };
  }
});

var note1 = new Note;
var note2 = new Note;
var note3 = new Note({author: 'Daniel!', coordinates:[9,9]});

console.log( note1.toJSON() );
console.log( note2.toJSON() );
console.log( note3.toJSON() );
```